# Get data, count and group by DATETIME where date gap greater than X

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a lot of sessions for a particular API running at once. Every now and then, the API will update causing all sessions to die.

When this happens, each session will report an error '830' back to my central website.

The data ends up looking something like this:

```
uid------error-------date
41       830         2018-05-14 13:45:13
42       830         2018-05-14 13:45:14
43       830         2018-05-14 13:45:16
44       830         2018-05-14 13:45:23
46       830         2018-05-14 13:46:19
50       830         2018-05-15 04:12:49
80       830         2018-05-15 04:12:49
36       830         2018-05-15 04:12:50
91       830         2018-05-15 04:15:52
12       830         2018-05-15 07:45:11
88       830         2018-05-15 07:45:11
92       830         2018-05-15 07:45:12
```

Because it can happen at any time, I need to be able to group this data by the gap between the next bit of data.

For instance, this is the output I want to get with the data above and output as such (Where gap >10 mins):

```
update_date-----update_count
2018-05-14      1
2018-05-15      2
```

Here's what I've been tried so far:

```
select
    count(eresult) as error_count,
    CAST(added AS DATE) as error_date
from st__errors
where 1=1
and eresult = 20
group by date(added)
order by id desc
```

Result:

[image]

This groups and counts all data but doesn't account for a gap and grouping by the date gap which is where I'm stuck.

I need the data to be grouped, per day, by the gap between each error date. I'm explaining myself really badly but hopefully the examples describe better what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it going to be a very slow query but it is an option:

```
select    count(e.eresult) as error_count,
          CAST(e.added AS DATE) as error_date
from      st__errors as e
where (
       SELECT  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(e.added, ei.added)) 
       FROM    st__errors as ei WHERE ei.id = e.id - 1
      ) > 10
      and e.eresult = 20
group by date(e.added)
order by e.id desc
```

Comment: Thank you - I was really struggling with this but reading through your answer it has become much more obvious what I needed to do and it works!! Appreciate it :)

Comment: While this may work, it's not recommended to rely on the ids to be consecutive or in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I think this can be done with a JOIN:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) grouped_error_count,
          DATE(e1.added) error_date
     FROM st__errors e1

/* Find other error within 10 mins */
LEFT JOIN st__errors e2
       ON e2.added < e1.added 
      AND e2.added >= e1.added - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE 

/* Find other error with exact same time (but only count one) */
LEFT JOIN st__errors e3
       ON e3.added = e1.added 
      AND e3.id < e1.id 

/* Has neither of the above */
    WHERE e2.id IS NULL
      AND e3.id IS NULL 

 GROUP BY error_date
 ORDER BY error_date DESC;
```

I'd stay away from using `id = id - 1` (or using id for ordering) because it relies on the ids being consecutive, which, even with auto_increment, is fallible when manual inserts are done or if certain inserts fail.

My query should still allow the use of an index on the added column.

Also, if this is going to be a feature rather than just a one off query, I'd look at building your grouping into the recording. This will make your queries a lot faster and more readable.

Comment: I have a lot of data in this table and it seems to be taking a long time to run - upwards of 5 minutes now and I've restarted my db once

Comment: do you have an index on `added`?

Comment: I'll get back to you soon, I'm creating a maintenance page so I can add the index without killing the site x) Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster way, but it sometimes sees one group as two.

```
SELECT FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) / (10*60)) AS ten_min_bucket,
       COUNT(*) AS err_ct
    FROM st__errors
    GROUP BY ten_min_bucket;
```

A variant lets you see the time range:

```
SELECT MIN(datetime) AS err_start,
       MAX(datetime) AS err_end,
       COUNT(*) AS err_ct
    FROM st__errors
    GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) / (10*60));
```

If you see one error clump starting seconds after the previous ended, you will know that they belong together.  Once you are used to that 'flaw', you might want to shrink the resolution down to 5 minutes.